# Automatically create links to content in a folder

Tags: umbraco

I have 2-3 HTML files created per week that will be uploaded via FTP to a folder on the web server. The files are just plain HTML having results from my local Bridge Club.

Before I go ahead and spending time creating a "fancy" solution in .Net for this I better ask if there is any built in support for this in Umbraco.

Basically I want to have a main menu item called Results, and that page should have a secondary menu with links to each .HTML file in a specific folder

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you put the path that the html files are being uploaded to within the `umbracoReservedPaths` app setting in the web.config.

Next I would create an [XSLT extension](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/Create_xslt_exstension_like_umbraco.Library_in_C) (or [custom function](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/extend-your-xslt-with-custom-functions) that returns an `XPathNodeIterator` containing each HTML file name. The method will need to build an XmlDocument that looks something like:

```
<files>
  <file>/htmlfiles/file1.html</file>
  <file>/htmlfiles/file2.html</file>
  <file>/htmlfiles/file3.html</file>
</files>
```

Then call `CreateNavigator()` on the XmlDocument and return that from the XSLT extension method. Use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) to get the list of HTML file names and convert them to a web ready URL like `/htmlfiles/file1.html`.

Then display it all with a simple XSLT macro that iterates the result of your XSLT extension in a for-each. That would look something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="customExtensions:GetFiles()//file">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:text>File #</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This would generate a list like

```
File #1
File #2
File #3
```

all linking to their respective value in the xml.

A good example of an extension method is [here](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/getmembersbygroupname)